# How to make a dynamic layout only by CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to create a layout like this:

1. The left column (yellow): width 150px **constant** - height **dynamic**
2. The middle column (azure): width **dynamic** - height **dynamic**
3. The right column (green): width 150px **constant** - height **dynamic**
4. The footer (red): width **dynamic** - height **constant**

*I'm looking for a CSS-only solution.*

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/centerwow/qXKZh/37/show/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://fiddle.jshell.net/2bSaP/show/

HTML :

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="yellow"></div>
    <div id="blue"></div>
    <div id="green"></div>
    <div id="red"></div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}

#yellow {
    background: yellow;
    position: absolute;
    width: 150px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 155px;
}

#blue {
    background: rgb(98, 196, 255);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 155px;
    left: 155px;
    bottom: 155px;
}

#green {
    background: green;
    position: absolute;
    width: 150px;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 155px;
}

#red {
    background: brown;
    position: absolute;
    height: 150px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Used 
 now you forget `position`  define `position value` in your css

as like this

```
#blue{
position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: I try it before when I asked here, it is not help me. I need to fill the the squere in the middle with the div #blue with any size resolution so the #blue will match the accurately the area. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you wanted, but I got rid of all those height rules for `#Blue` and just added `height: 100%`, then gave `#Red` a higher `z-index` (55, for instance).

Now the center square appears to always be blue.

http://jsfiddle.net/qXKZh/38/

Hope this helps

Comment: I could do that before I asked, this is not solution

Answer (score 0):

I'm really not sure what you're trying to accomplish. Is it supposed to look the way MusikAnimal's jsfiddle looks?

If so, I'd go for a different structure (complete with the right heights and widths...):

```
<div id="for3columns" style="height: 500px;">
  <div id="yellow_column" style="float: left; width: 20%; height: 100%"></div>
  <div id="blue_column" style="float: left; width: 60%; height: 100%"></div>
  <div id="green_column" style="float: left; width: 20%; height: 100%"></div>
</div>
<div id="lower_red" style="clear:both; width: 100%; height: 100px;"></div>
```

Comment: Yes but when you say yellow_column,green_column width20% it is constant of 150px .blue_column it is not constant  it is need to match to any resolution width it is meen that he dynamic width and dynamic height this is the problem.

Comment: and lower_red it is height 150px constant but width it is dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little difficult to understand what your question is, but from what I gather, I was able to get to this solution: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aniketpant/T8Kdm/)

### HTML

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='col col-left'></div>
    <div class='col col-mid'></div>
    <div class='col col-right'></div>
    <div class='col col-bottom'></div>
</div>​
```

### CSS

```
.container {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.col {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
}

.col-left {
    width: 25%;
    height: 200px;
    background: #f90a7b;
}

.col-mid {
    width: 50%;
    height: 200px;
    background: #e3f606;
}

.col-right {
    width: 25%;
    height: 200px;     
    background: #46c704;
}

.col-bottom {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background: #0654e0;
}​
```

Comment: Yes but when you say yellow_column,green_column width25% it is constant of 150px .blue_column it is not constant it is need to match to any resolution width it is meen that he dynamic width and dynamic height this is the problem,and lower_red it is height 150px constant but width it is dynamic.