# 3 column layout with 100% width and variable centered div

Tags: html, css, layout

I want to create a 3 column layout with one centered div, one left and one right div. The left and right divs should expand from the centered div to the left and right end of the page. The centered div contains elements with transparent regions and therefore the centered div should not overlap the left and right divs. I managed to create a solution if the centered div has a fixed width. The question is, is it possible to create a similar layout but with a cented div with dynamic width?

[jsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/FCR64/)

Here is the code for fixed width.

CSS:

```
#divCenter{
  position:absolute;
  top:0%;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  height:50px;
  width:500px;
  margin:0 auto;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaff;
  background:#aaaaff;
  z-index:2;
}
#divLeft{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0%;
  width:50%;
  border: 1px solid #aaffaa;
  z-index:1;
}
#divLeftInner{
  height:60px;
  margin-right:250px;
  background:#aaffaa;
}
#divRight{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0%;
  width:50%;
  border: 1px solid #ffaaaa;
  z-index:1;
}
#divRightInner{
  height:60px;
  margin-left:250px;
  background:#ffaaaa;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="divCenter">
</div>
<div id="divLeft">
  <div id="divLeftInner">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="divRight">
  <div id="divRightInner">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems like you are looking for something like this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11356283/how-to-make-a-dynamic-layout-only-by-css/11381054

Answer (score 1):

Float all columns left and set the left and right columns to have equal width - using JavaScript.

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="left" class="col"></div>
    <div id="mid" class="col"></div>
    <div id="right" class="col"></div>
</div>​
```

**CSS**

```
.col {float:left;height:200px;}
#left, #right {width:30%;background:red;}
#mid {width:40%;background:blue;}
```

**jQuery**

```
//extra verbose for clarity's sake
var setWidths = function() {
    var wrapWidth = $("#wrapper").width();
    var midWidth = $("#mid").width();
    var leftOverWidth = wrapWidth - midWidth;
    var sideColWidth = leftOverWidth/2;
    $(".sidecol").width(sideColWidth);
}

//set new sizes whenever the window is resized
$(window).on("resize", setWidths);

$(function() {
    setWidths(); //set correct sizes when the DOM has loaded
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GYGL3/37/

Comment: Oh I see. Sorry for missing that small detail. :) I think you need to use JavaScript for such a solution. Let me update my answer for you, hold on...

Comment: Updated. As far as _I_ know what you're asking for isn't doable width just CSS.

Comment: Thanks for the code - it seems to work. Anyway, I don’t want to rely on enabled JavaScript for that layout. If it is not possible with just CSS, I will go with my solution with a fixed width centered div.

Comment: For this to work with simply CSS you'd basically need to be able to say "width: 50% of the remaining space" somehow, which I think is impossible. But I wish I'm wrong, because it would be really useful.